# NetBeans - How to use unverified plugins?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Every time I get an update on NetBeans or on some plugin, I have to wait several days for the verification & activation; is there a way to activate (and use) the unverified plugins on NB?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the updated plugin ***manually*** through the [**plugin portal**](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/).

---

#### Some background:

Once a developer releases a plugin (or updates one), it's first published into the plugin portal. Afterwards it's necessary to request *verification* – a QA by some Netbeans memebers – before it's available through the IDE (and auto update).

This usually takes some days (unfortunately …), as at least two people have to review it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; the plugin appears on plugin portal but it seems not verified but it has been updated automatically by the IDE; the plugin's name is nbmongo.

Comment: As the plugin needs to be verified before it gets delivered through the IDE updater, maybe it's already a newer version at website (or you have received an earlier version)? It's possible that the version of website and IDE differ; the former always provides the latest version, while the latter has the latest *verified* version. In case of doubt, you can compare both versions manually.

Comment: The [verification is still in progress](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52638/nbmongo); only 1 of 2 *Go*'s yet. If this takes longer you (or the developer) can inform the verification guys (there's a mailing list for those issues), to speed up.